# Is there any simple Lakshmi-Narasimha mantra for daily recitation?

Tags: mantras, lakshmi, narasimha

I have been doing

> Sri Lakshmi Narayanai Namah

for a while. I am looking for a similar simple mantra for Lakshmi-Narasimha.
All I get in the internet are big, complicated ones which I am not comfortable doing without a guru and I am not in a position to go look for a guru at this point.

I really appreciate any help in this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mantra which I have seen on the cover of Narsimha Puran by Gita Press is Om ShriLakshmiNrsimhabhyam Namah (ॐ श्रीलक्ष्मीनृसिंहाभ्याम नमः).

Comment: thank you so much